# Unable to compute a Delete Query with Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

```
    `IF(@ParentField = 'Reason for call - Primary Issue')
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM dbo.ControlBrandMapping CBM
            INNER JOIN dbo.ControlManagement CM ON CM.ID = CBM.CONTROLID
                WHERE CM.DefaultName = 'Reason for call - Sub Issue' AND CBM.BRANDID = @BrandId
    END`
```

I tried my best to make it look as neat as possible.
I am getting this error - "Incorrect syntax near 'CBM'."
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the alias `CBM` after the `DELETE` clause. Try this instead:

```
    DELETE CBM
    FROM dbo.ControlBrandMapping CBM
    INNER JOIN dbo.ControlManagement CM ON CM.ID = CBM.CONTROLID
    WHERE CM.DefaultName = 'Reason for call - Sub Issue' 
      AND @ParentField = 'Reason for call - Primary Issue'
      AND CBM.BRANDID = @BrandId
```

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means sure about it, I just started but from what I know, When doing joins I think it should be `INNER JOIN dbo.ControlManagement CM ON (CM.ID = CBM.CONTROLID)`
note the brackets, But I may be wrong

Comment: i just skipped the CBM after Delete. The brackets arent necessary.